# Por quê usar MutationObserver no lugar de Mutation events?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Bom o título é a pergunta por si só, eu sei que é porque os *Mutation events* não serão continuados mais, mas:

- Qual a diferença entre um e outro (não de como usar, mas sim do conceito técnico)?
- Por quê os *browsers* optaram por essa mudança?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na própria documentação da [MDN acerca dos *Mutation Events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) há:

> *The practical reasons to avoid the mutation events are performance issues and cross-browser support.*

Na mesma documentação ainda é citado que o problema de performance se dá ao adicionar os *listeners* de mutações do DOM, degradando o desempenho de outras mutações no DOm no documento, deixando de 1.5 a 7 vezes mais lento; e diz ainda que ao remover os *listeners*, essa degradação se mantém. Sem muitos detalhes do que motiva a degradação, é deixado o [link para uma lista de e-mails](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/L0Lx11u5Bvs) onde o problema é discutido.

Quanto ao suporte entre navegadores se dá devido a não consistência da implementação de tais eventos. São citados alguns exemplos:

- IE, em versões anteriores ao 9, não suportam os *mutation events* e sua implementação na versão 9 foi mal feita;
- WebKit não suporta `DOMAttrModified`;
- "*mutation name events*", isto é, `DOMElementNameChanged` e `DOMAttributeNameChanged` não são suportados pelo Firefox;

É citado ainda que, para entender o motivo da mudança, recomenda-se ler [*DOM Mutation Events Replacement: The Story So Far / Existing Points of Consensus*](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011JulSep/0779.html), que tentarei traduzir livremente abaixo.

---

### DOM Mutation Events Replacement: The Story So Far / Existing Points of Consensus

O que se segue é uma tentativa de resumir a recente (2011) discussão sobre a substituição do DOM Mutation Events.

#### Meus objetivos aqui são:

- Prover um breve resumo para aqueles que não leram todos os e-mails;
- Reiterar os aspectos da solução que parece bem apoiada;
- Identificar os principais pontos de divergência que ainda restaram;

Problema: DOM Mutation Events são, conforme especificação e implementação atual, amplamente considerados fatalmente falhos porque:

1. Verboso;
2. Lento (devido à propagação de eventos e porque isso impede algumas otimizações do navegador em tempo de execução);
3. "Quebrável" (tem sido a fonte de muitas falhas nos navegadores porque o script pode destruir o mundo da forma que desejar enquanto uma operação DOM está em andamento);

#### Solução:

**Pontos com grande aprovação**

Principalmente devido a uma proposta feita por Jonas Sicking em 2009, o grupo concordou amplamente sobre o seguinte:

1. O vocabulário das mutações deve ser mais expressivo e exigir menos "palavras" para descrever adequadamente o que aconteceu. Por exemplo, uma única atribuição `innerHTML` que resulta na remoção de N nós e na inserção de M nós deve ser expressa como uma única mutação (por exemplo, `{mutação: "ChildlistChanged", adicionada: [...], removida: [...]}`) - não uma seqüência de mutações, uma para cada nó inserido ou removido;
2. As mutações devem evitar a despesa de propagação de eventos (principalmente captura e borbulhamento);
3. As mutações devem ser entregues aos observadores após as operações de DOM que os geraram serem finalizadas - removendo a possibilidade de que o *script* interfira com a operação. Por exemplo, uma operação `execCommand()` é permitida para fazer qualquer e todas as operações DOM necessárias antes deve notificar qualquer observador do que aconteceu;

Ao discutir a proposta de Jonas, observamos que, em um sistema que permite múltiplos observadores que podem, eles próprios, fazer mutações, os observadores geralmente precisam ser tolerantes com um número arbitrário de mutações ocorridas antes de serem notificadas.

Além disso, há uma forte motivação de desempenho para os observadores responderem ao efeito de rede de um conjunto de mutações, ao invés de agir de imediato em resposta a cada mutação.

Portanto:

4. Os observadores devem ser chamados com o conjunto de mutações que ocorreu desde que foram chamadas pela última vez (ou desde o registro), em vez de serem chamadas uma vez por mutação. Isto é, Entregue mutações em lotes de "tudo o que aconteceu desde a última vez que eu liguei para você - até agora";

Para o meu entender, as propostas mais recentes feitas por Jonas, Olli Pettay, Adam Klein e eu concordamos nos quatro pontos de design acima.

**Pontos ainda sem consenso**

5. Quando as mutações são entregues? Existem quatro opções aqui, apenas duas das quais têm proponentes (foi assunto de outro e-mail);
6. A semântica para expressar interesse em conjuntos de nós;
7. Qual informação está contida nos registros de mutação;

---

Quanto aos pontos que não estavam em consenso, penso que atualmente já foram resolvidos, dado que o *DOM Mutation Events* já foi declarado como obsoleto em prol do *MutationObserver*, então verei se encontro parte da discussão ou fonte oficial que trata quais foram os termos acordados.